# Запятая после оборота, начинающегося словом «который»

Tags: запятые, спп

Обратите внимание, что реклама, которую вы встречаете при просмотре видео(,) не относится к приложению.

Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая необходима, так как она закрывает придаточное предложение «...которую вы встречаете при просмотре видео»:

> Обратите внимание, что реклама, которую вы встречаете при просмотре видео, не относится к приложению.

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятая безусловно нужна.

[КОТО́РЫЙ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/842334), кото́рая, кото́рое, *местоимение.*
4. *относит.* Служит для соединения придаточного предложения с главным и заменяет в придаточном предложении существительное, находящееся в главном.

Придаточное предложение заканчивается словом "видео", после него и ставится вторая запятая.

*Обратите внимание, что реклама, **которую вы встречаете при просмотре видео,** не относится к приложению.*

Вот интересное предложение, демонстрирующее это правило (автора не нашла):
*Ты — это книги, которые ты читаешь, фильмы, которые ты смотришь, музыка, которую ты слушаешь, люди, которых ты встречаешь, мечты, которые ты имеешь, разговоры, в которых ты участвуешь.*